# WEKA LibSVM don't work with my dataset

Tags: machine-learning, weka, libsvm

The LibSVM on WEKA isn't loading with my dataset.
I am using WEKA and LibSVM. Every time I open my dataset and then try to chose an algorithm, the LibSVM algorithm isn't enabled (the option is gray). But if for instance I load the weather.arff example dataset that comes with the WEKA then the LibSVM algorithm works...

I don't know if there is anything wrong with my dataset. Are there any limitations that I should be aware of when dealing with LibSVM? For instance, number of attributes, etc.

The strange thing is that when I run my dataset with the SMO algorith that comes with WEKA it works without any problem.

In my dataset I have 76 attributes and my class attribute has 100 possible values.

Am I doing anything wrong? Thanks, very appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your dataset doesn't match input format required by LibSVM. The capabilities are as follows:

```
CAPABILITIES
Class -- Nominal class, Missing class values, Binary class

Attributes -- Empty nominal attributes, Nominal attributes, Unary attributes, Binary attributes, Date attributes, Numeric attributes

Additional
min # of instances: 1
```

So the class in your .arff file should be either nominal or binary (allowed to miss some values) and your attributes should be nominal, unary or binary (allowed to be empty).

Comment: I got it to work now but I had to delete some of my attributes. The interesting thing is that those attributes I have deleted they were numerical with some missing values. With LibSVM can I have numerical attributes with missing values ?

Comment: Nope; As you can see above, numerical attributes are not part of the capabilities of LibSVM. You can use the `Discretize` or `NumericToNominal` filter to change your numeric attributes to nominal.